Why does my service that starts an ASP.NET Core app not work with local system account?
I created my app and it works fine. I registered a service in Program.cs:
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices;

var options = new WebApplicationOptions
{
    Args = args,
    ContentRootPath = WindowsServiceHelpers.IsWindowsService()
                                     ? AppContext.BaseDirectory : default
};

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(options);
...
builder.Services.AddWindowsService();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<MicroinvestIOService>();// this is the name of my service


And this is the code in MicroinvestIOService:
public class MicroinvestIOService : BackgroundService
{
    public MicroinvestIOService(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        Logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<MicroinvestIOService>();
    }

    public ILogger Logger { get; }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        Logger.LogInformation("MicroinvestIOService is starting.");

        stoppingToken.Register(() => Logger.LogInformation("ServiceA is stopping."));

        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Logger.LogInformation("MicroinvestIOService is doing background work.");

            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), stoppingToken);
        }

        Logger.LogInformation("ServiceA has stopped.");
    }
}

And then I registered my service with CMD
sc create MicroinvestIO binpath="the path of my exe file"

BUT: everything works fine when the account, starting my service, is my current PC administrator.
When I try to run it with "Local System" account, it stops after maybe 5 or 10 seconds.
I even tried to create another administrator's account, but it fails again!
Any ideas?
Edit:
I removed this:
builder.Services.AddHostedService();
The result is the same.

What does your logging tells you?

In services.msc I don't receive message. In Event Viewer: Hosting failed to start
Exception:
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.   --- It is more but is to long for here.

Then how is your certificate setup for this? Or where you just lucky till now because you are the developer on the developer machine that got a certificate as a gift while installing Visual Studio?

I am sure that certificate is is not important, because I use localhost. I can start my server as http, but the result will be the same. I did it with other app on one of my local machines, surving other SQL databases.

Since your issue occurs while changing the account, have you checked the permissions of on the folder of your different accounts? I cannot reproduce it on my machine , so please try this if you find no differences https://d4dpkrajput.medium.com/unable-to-configure-https-endpoint-ef85ec54e046 .

So, I did it! Ralph, You were absolutely right! Without certificate the endpoint, described in my appsettings.json for https redirection don't work. I have 2 options:

To remove the https endpoint:
"Kestrel": {
"Endpoints": {
"Http": {
"Url": "http://0.0.0.0:5000"
}


or
2. To generate certificate for ASP.NET with command "dotnet dev-certs https --trust", then export certificate in my working folder and describe it in appsettings.json:
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://0.0.0.0:5000"
      },
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:5001",
        "Certificate": {
          "Path": "D:\\Temp\\MicroinvestIO\\Certificate.pfx",
          "Password": "my password" - used when exporting certificate
        }

      }
    }

